# How to display &Delta; in Highcharts category labels?

Tags: highcharts

I've come across an issue that I'm pretty sure it's just where I'm setting my object value, however, I can't seem to get this to work.

I'm attempting to put the Δ character in the highcharts.js category as seen in this code snippet below:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Catawba Average Points'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Emergency TS &Delta;s', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D', 'Column E', 'Column F', 'Column G'],
    labels: {
      useHtml: true
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      groupPadding: 0.10,
      pointPadding: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        alignt: 'right',
        formatter: function() {
          if (this.y != 0) {
            return this.y;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: '(-) Var',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    color: '#ffa6a6',
    stack: '2017Q3',
    showInLegend: false
  }, {
    name: '(+) Var',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, .1, 0, 0, 5.10],
    color: '#a6e3c2',
    stack: '2017Q2',
    showInLegend: false
  }, {
    name: '2017Q3',
    color: '#d9d9d9',
    data: [10, 15, 10, 10, 3.1, 0, 25, 15],
    stack: '2017Q3'
  }, {
    name: '2017Q2',
    color: '#f2f2f2',
    data: [10, 15, 10, 10, 3.0, 2, 25, 9.90],
    stack: '2017Q2'
  }]


});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I've tried putting the useHtml in several places to no avail. Any thoughts to what I'm doing wrong?

Here is a fiddle to play around with as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/crk3vn76/

**EDIT**

Note, the data comes from a database, and if I put the Δ in directly, it renders as a ?

**EDIT 2**

Okay, so this will work if I set my charset to utf-8 in the database and put the Δ directly in there. However, I'd still like to figure out how to do this using the html character code.

Comment: If I use your jsFiddle and put in "Δ" explicitly it does render correctly. What is your site's code page? It needs to be UTF-8 as far as I know to render this directly.

Comment: @wergeld check my **edit 2**, I realized my table wasn't utf-8, but I'd still like to try to figure out how to render the html codes as well.

Comment: Doesn't look like Highcharts supports this - it might be inserting the label as text, not HTML, which means character references will never work. You'll have to either use the character directly, or use an escape sequence within the JavaScript.

Comment: @BoltClock it was a case sensitivity issue. My old eyes are deceiving me when it comes to simple reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating my own [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91z6sL8u/7/) to work with, it appears the configuration [useHTML](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML) is case-sensitive and changing `useHTML` to `useHTML` correctly creates `Δ` in the categories

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Catawba Average Points'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Emergency TS &Delta;s', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D', 'Column E', 'Column F', 'Column G'],
    labels: {
      useHTML: true
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      groupPadding: 0.10,
      pointPadding: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        alignt: 'right',
        formatter: function() {
          if (this.y != 0) {
            return this.y;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: '(-) Var',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    color: '#ffa6a6',
    stack: '2017Q3',
    showInLegend: false
  }, {
    name: '(+) Var',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, .1, 0, 0, 5.10],
    color: '#a6e3c2',
    stack: '2017Q2',
    showInLegend: false
  }, {
    name: '2017Q3',
    color: '#d9d9d9',
    data: [10, 15, 10, 10, 3.1, 0, 25, 15],
    stack: '2017Q3'
  }, {
    name: '2017Q2',
    color: '#f2f2f2',
    data: [10, 15, 10, 10, 3.0, 2, 25, 9.90],
    stack: '2017Q2'
  }]


});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Ah ha! I this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the unicode representation as `\u0394`. This appears to work with `labels.useHTML: true`.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Catawba Average Points'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Emergency TS \u0394s', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D', 'Column E', 'Column F', 'Column G'],
    labels: {useHtml: true}
  },

  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      groupPadding: 0.10,
      pointPadding: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        alignt: 'right',
        formatter: function(){
        if(this.y != 0){
         return this.y;
        }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: '(-) Var',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    color: '#ffa6a6',
    stack: '2017Q3'
  }, {
    name: '(+) Var',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, .1, 0, 0, 5.10],
    color: '#a6e3c2',
    stack: '2017Q2'
  }, {
    name: '2017Q3',
    color: '#d9d9d9',
    data: [10, 15, 10, 10, 3.1, 0, 25, 15],
    stack: '2017Q3'
  }, {
    name: '2017Q2',
    color: '#f2f2f2',
    data: [10, 15, 10, 10, 3.0, 2, 25, 9.90],
    stack: '2017Q2'
  }]


});
```

Comment: looks like the issue was useHTML vs useHtml as @Wondercricket pointed out